# return a string in C++

Tags: c++

I have a function in my C++ where I would like to return a string. I have tried a few ways but get errors. I've tried the C# way of return "...."; return myString; But get errors every time.

EDIT:

Unhandled exception at 0x100c1486 (DGGGGG.dll) in TestConsoleApp2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x7a0dcc30.

Comment: errors? What errors? Dont see them in your question...

Comment: Can you please be clearer?
Please?

Comment: Using my psychic abilities, I'm guessing either A) You are not including the header `<string>`. Or B) You are not qualifying the string class name with `std`.

Comment: please see the edit for the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
std::string methodReturningString()
{
    std::string something = "Hello ";
    something += "world!";
    return something;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this public? I have created public methods using:
extern "C"<br />

  __declspec(dllexport) string returnSomething()
  {
   ....................
  }
}